# Convert From Epoch to Date String

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert from epoch time (numeric) to a string date.   I have these two values, from October of last year to March of this year: 1349064000000,1362114000000.  But when I do Date(num), I get today's date returned for both.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `new Date(num)`.

`Date()`, without "new", doesn't create a  new Date object, it only returns the current date as a string, regardless of any arguments you pass.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:-

```
var date = new Date(1349064000000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It will alert your wanted date.

```
var utcSeconds = 1349064000;
var d = new Date(0); 
d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);

alert(d);
```